# Add data attribute in each element from highest to lowest in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code

```
<ul>
    <li class="test" data-id="3">hi</li>
    <li class="test" data-id="5">hey</li>
    <li class="test" data-id="1">hello</li>
    <li class="test" data-id="17">Okay</li>
</ul>
```

Need to add **data-order** attribute in each element by highest to lowest value, like this

```
<ul>
    <li class="test" data-order="3" data-id="3">hi</li>
    <li class="test" data-order="2" data-id="5">hey</li>
    <li class="test" data-order="4" data-id="1">hello</li>
    <li class="test" data-order="1" data-id="17">Okay</li>
</ul>
```

So, the one whose value is the highest will be added **data-order="1"**, and the same way for the rest.

Comment: based on data-id

Comment: i suppose you are using loop to add data attribute to each li, isn't it?

Comment: can you please share the code, that is adding `data-id` attribute to each li?

Comment: this is static code, and need to add data-order using jquery based on data-id

Comment: @sarfaraj I don't see your attempt anywhere on trying to create this yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following snippet demonstrates one option. Changing the `text` is just for demonstration.

```js
$(() => {
  $('li')
    .toArray()
    .sort((a,b) => $(b).data('id') - $(a).data('id'))
    .map((e,i) => $(e).data('order', i+1).text(i+1))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
    <li class="test" data-id="3">hi</li>
    <li class="test" data-id="5">hey</li>
    <li class="test" data-id="1">hello</li>
    <li class="test" data-id="17">Okay</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: How to add **data-order** attribute

Comment: @sarfaraj It is added, but as property, not attribute. If you need it as attribute use `attr('data-order', i+1)` instead of `data('order', i+1)`. In general you don't need it as attribute.

Comment: @sarfaraj During parsing, data attributes are automatically added to the data properties, but not the other way.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps you need to follow

- Get all the values of `li`
- Sort the array
- Now append the order to the `li`

```js
function sortNumber(a, b) {
  return b - a;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  let allVal = [];
  $('ul li').each(function(i) {
    allVal.push(parseInt($(this).attr('data-id'), 10));
  });
  allVal = allVal.sort(sortNumber);

  $('ul li').each(function(i) {
    let id = parseInt($(this).attr('data-id'), 10);
    $(this).attr('data-order', allVal.indexOf(id) + 1);
  });


});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="test" data-id="3">hi</li>
  <li class="test" data-id="5">hey</li>
  <li class="test" data-id="1">hello</li>
  <li class="test" data-id="17">Okay</li>
</ul>
```

```js
function sortNumber(a, b) {
  return b - a;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  let allVal = [];
  $('ul li').each(function(i) {
    allVal.push(parseInt($(this).attr('data-id'), 10));
  });
  allVal = allVal.sort(sortNumber);

  $('ul li').each(function(i) {
    let id = parseInt($(this).attr('data-id'), 10);
    let text = $(this).text();
    $(this).attr('data-order', allVal.indexOf(id) + 1).text(text + ' Order =' + (allVal.indexOf(id) + 1) );
  });


});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="test" data-id="3">hi</li>
  <li class="test" data-id="5">hey</li>
  <li class="test" data-id="1">hello</li>
  <li class="test" data-id="17">Okay</li>
</ul>
```

[image]